# Shopping Cart Total amount

Tags: jquery, sum

When i enter value into qty textfield, the amt field should be automatically calculated.. For each row it should do the same..Tis is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".qty").change(function(){
$(".amt").val(this.value*($("#amt").val()))
});
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: provide relevant HTML code

Comment: it is better if you can share a jsfiddle link

Comment: can you check the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".qty").change(function(){
     $(".amt").val($(this).val()*($("#amt").val()))
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide html also

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle:

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uWbd/6/)

And this the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".qty").keyup(function(){
        $(".amt").val($(this).val()*$(".amt").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: the before fiddle is also working if you put some value in second input box and then update the first input box

Comment: Did you check it out?

Comment: U r using oly 1 set of fields... Am asking to calculate each item's total as i add a new row... Check tis http://jsfiddle.net/7uWbd/13/

Comment: I got the Amount now.. Now i hav problem with the Grand Total.. I was the sum of al the amt values...

Comment: We are not here for your homework dude... If this answer helped you kindly upvote and check it.

Comment: U hav used only 1 set of fields.. See the image properly.. I hav a collection of Amt fields.. Wit single field even i can do it... And i will upvote only if the answer suits me..

Comment: Ok we are here to help you out not to do your task. I showed you the way it can be done. Now you figure out the way you want it to be done. And I seriously don't need your upvote. Thankz anyways.

Answer (score 0):

first add class='amountValue' to input tag from where you are taking amount value and then try below code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".qty").change(function(){
 // put class='amountValue' for every input tag where you have your amount value
 // get the value of it
 var amountValue = this.closest('td').prev('td').find('.amountValue').val();
 // get quantity
 var qunatity = this.val();
 // calculate total amount
 var totalAmount = qunatity * amountValue;
 // and put the totalAmount in next input with class='amt'
 this.closest('td').next('td').find('.amt').val(totalAmount);
});
});
</script>
```